# Unity compile error with Nethereum and Newton.Json

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine, json.net, nethereum, newtonscript

Hi I created a brand new project in unity3d and imported the Nethereum sdk. When I try adding any scripts I keep receiving a compile error -

`The type 'JsonSerializerSettings' is defined in an assembly that is not referenced. You must add a reference to assembly 'Newtonsoft.Json, Version=12.0.0.0, Culture=neutral,...`

I've tried several things such as importing package from asset store, importing package from VS, I tried adding a web.config with the reference, etc.

What am I doing wrong?

Comment: While working with Nethereum, I remember removing entry for **"com.unity.collab-proxy"** from `Packages/manifest.json` file and then importing Nethereum files. I used [net472dll.zip](https://github.com/Nethereum/Nethereum/releases/download/4.0.5/net472dlls.zip)

Comment: @nIcEcOw wow that worked! I've been trying to figure this out for days now. Thank you! The only difference is that I used the unitynet35dlls package.

Comment: Wow, glad it worked for you. For the rest You're MOST WELCOME and KEEP SMILING :-) In unitynet35dlls, it seems might be they don't have support for **chainId**, that is why I went for the other DLLs. Not sure though, since I also did tried many thingies before making it work :-)